# Counting value based on 2 other columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, count

How to count the value as shows in the below example in vba or excel formula,  Count column should have a value of the combination of column1 and column2.

[image: Sample data table which i want to achieve]

Answer (score 2):

### Compare-Count Two Columns

- If the code is in the workbook containing the worksheet, then you could replace `Range(FirstCell)` with e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(FirstCell)` to make sure it runs on the right worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub compareCountTwoColumns()
    
    Const FirstCell As String = "A2"
    
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range(FirstCell)
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, 2)
        Set rng = rng.Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, "No Data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1, 2)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    Dim Previous As Variant: ReDim Previous(1 To 2)
    Previous(1) = Data(1, 1): Previous(2) = Data(1, 2)
    Dim Current As Variant: ReDim Current(1 To 2)
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim cCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Current(1) = Data(i, 1): Current(2) = Data(i, 2)
        If Previous(1) <> Current(1) Or Previous(2) <> Current(2) Then
            Result(i - 1, 1) = cCount
            cCount = 1
        Else
            cCount = cCount + 1
        End If
        Previous(1) = Current(1): Previous(2) = Current(2)
    Next i
    Result(i - 1, 1) = cCount
    
    rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2).Value = Result

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, you did lots of effort to write this code, I appreciate it, but i found one formula which was effortless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER:

paste this formula into column 3: `=IF(AND(A4=A5,B4=B5),"",SUM(IF(A1=$A$1:$A$12,1,0)*IF(B1=$B$1:$B$12,1,0)))`.
Make sure you resize the range in both IF statements to fit your entire range...

---

OLD ANSWER:

Quick solution (with helper column, this assumes that your data starts in cell A!):

1. In third column put this formula and drag down `=A4&B4`
2. In fourth column put this `=IF(C2=C1,"",COUNTIF($C$1:$C$12,C1))`

note: this will break if you have `20 | 1` and `2 | 01` in which it will group them in their count.

also, make sure to adjust `COUNTIF($C$1:$C$12,C1)` to fit your entire range

Comment: @Dev, I tried your new answer, but nothing was printed it is blank.

Comment: I need to deal with 2 million rows, may be i need vba code to iterate through each row and column to count it, as of none of the answer worked, I appreciate your help guys. I am in UK, already mid night, I will try tomorrow morning again.

Comment: you might need vba :). that's a lot of rows

Comment: *"I need to deal with 2 million rows"* - how do you handle this given a current rows count of 1,048,576? There is no hint in the original post. @jks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF`/`COUNTIFS` in single formula:

```
=IF(A1&B1<>A2&B2,COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9,B1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: this will break if you have 2 columns like 20 | 1 and 2 | 01, because when you concatenate them together, they look the same

Comment: @Dave No, it will not work only if these values follow each other. In that case, a separator must be added when comparing entries, e.g. ```A1&"_"&B1<>A2&"_"&B2```

Comment: That is what I meant. Nice fix though :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from another forum, here i am posting for another person who is looking for solution.

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1),COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1),"")`

Answer (score -2):

Excel has a COUNT formula that does exactly that. Just type =COUNT() and insert the range as a parameter and you'll obtain that result.

EDIT:
Seems like I was totaling missing the point.
Don't know VB so here's an excel solution.

Provided the values are ordered like in the example.

One solution could be first generating a unique hash column using a prime exponent for each column. `=POWER(2,D5)*POWER(3,E5)`.

Then generating a second column that counts values until it breaks `=IF(G5=G4,I4+1,1)`

Then a third column that shows only the relevant counts that is actually what you are looking for `=IF(I5<I6,"",I5)`

Comment: You didn't understand the question.  as long as column1 has 20, keep count column2 until it has same number and at the end write the total count in the next column. Count does only one column range.